# Trying to run a jar file with bat

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a regular .jar not runable .jar  file using a .bat file

The jar file is named `mytest.jar`, and I'm trying to execute it using in the .bat file:

```
java -classpath "mytest.jar"
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: You will have to define, "doesn't work".

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? You need to specify the class where your main() method resides after the .jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If it is an executable jar

You need to put the `-jar` flag.

Use:

```
java -jar /path/to/your/jar/mytest.jar
```

## If it is a regular jar file

you need to use:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH:/path/to/your/jar/mytest.jar YourMainClass
```

and on Windows,

```
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;/path/to/your/jar/mytest.jar YourMainClass
```

Comment: its not a runbale jar its reguler one... that has the source code

Comment: @GalSosin read the duplicate question .

Comment: @GalSosin I made an edit to your question

Comment: Dosent work and the question duplicate its for runnbale jar

Comment: Do you get and errors throws? Can you post the code of your main class or the error which is throws?